# Is there a way to create a Rules component programmatically?

Tags: 7, rules

Is there a way to programmatically create a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) component?

I mean a component like the ones listed on `/admin/config/workflow/rules/components`.

Comment: Did you refer to the docs or API for Rules?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found how it in the docs for Rules. And even in the module sources. I found how to create a rule. But about creating of components - I haven't.

Comment: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules/tree/rules.api.php#n494  "component: If set to TRUE, the rules admin UI will list elements of those plugin in the components UI and allows the creation of new components based upon this plugin. Optional."

Answer (score 0):

Rule components can be programmatically created- although they can be quite cumbersome to code from scratch.  I'd recommend building a component with some conditions, actions, and rulesets and exporting it.  Then you can analyze the exported php to determine how to define your custom component set.

You'll most likely want to reference:

1. A list of the hooks available for the D7 version of the Rules module can be found here:  http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/group/rules_hooks/7
2. A good set of Developer Documentation for custom rules (albeit an old set of documentation for the D6 version of Rules) can be found here:  https://www.drupal.org/node/298486